# reveal.js how to add an image to a slide

Tags: reveal.js

I am trying to use reveal.js for my presentation. I tried to add an image to my slide but the image won't show up. Here is my code

```
  <section>
    <h3>Slide Header</h3>
    <ul >
      <li >Symptom:  <img src="tmp_warning.png"  height="100" width="200">  </li>
      <li >Cause: unknown</li>
      <li >Steps to fix: unknown</li>
    </ul>                 
  </section>
```

What did i miss?

Comment: This is documented under media: https://revealjs.com/media/

Answer (score 6):

I need to put image file in .\public\images folder and then specify the path

```
<img src="/images/tmp_warning.png"  height="100" width="200">
```

And that fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm a little late on that issue, but you need to change `src` to `data-src`
Example:

```
<img data-src="myImage.png" height="420" width="200" />
```

Comment: No, both `src` and `data-src` should work for showing an image, so if one does not work, changing to the other is unlikely to help. The difference is just that `data-src` loads the image lazily - see https://revealjs.com/media/

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because that, when your presenter (e.g. google-chrome) compiling the `.js` file, it can't find where the image is.

So the solution is,
(1) You can just put the reveal.js and the image 'tmp_warning.png' under the same directory;
(2) Specify the path to 'tmp_warning.png' in code as below,

```
<img src="{YOU_OWN_PATH_TO}/tmp_warning.png"  height="100" width="200">
```

**noted** that, when you use a relative path to the image, you should address the path as the one that's relative to where the .js file is.